# Tips on creating a plug-in architecture for WPF

Tags: wpf, plugins, architecture, extensibility

I'm making the switch from Winforms to WPF.  In Winforms I have a plug-in architecture where a user control is hosted in a Winform.  Does anyone have any suggestions on creating a plug-in architecture for WPF?  I want to rally the forces of the developers in my community to further extend my products so I believe in an extensible framework for my apps.  I'm just starting WPF so I'm not sure what the best way is to go about this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look into the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You might find the article about [modular architecture](https://github.com/jbe2277/waf/wiki/Modular-Architecture) for WPF applications interessting as well. Please not that a plugin is the same thing as a module in this aspect.

The Information Manager sample application of the [WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com) shows how to apply these concepts to create a plug-in architecture. It uses MEF as well to discover and load the Plug-Ins.